# ostringstream variable not working

Tags: c++, mysql

i have the following code in a function->

```
                 ostringstream loading_csv_query;
                 ostringstream get_last_id_query;
                 in.getline(h1,255);
                 previouscount=this->getlastcount();
                 get_last_id_query << "set @count= "
                                   << previouscount ;
                 string pp=get_last_id_query.str();
                 if(mysql_query(con,get_last_id_query.str().c_str()))
                 loading_csv_query << "LOAD DATA INFILE '" << h1 << "' " 
                               << "INTO TABLE "<< g
                               << "FIELDS  TERMINATED BY ',' "
                               << "ENCLOSED BY '\"' "
                               << "LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' "
                               << "IGNORE 2 ROWS"
                               <<"(@sno,@var1,line,section,station,system,sub_system,equipment,sub_equipment,failure_time,rectified_time,duration,failure_description,rectification,lmd,origin,attended_by,reported_by,urr,@a1,@a2,@a3)"
                               <<"set id = (@count :=@count+1), failure_date =STR_TO_DATE(@var1, '%c/%e/%Y')";
        string h=loading_csv_query.str();
        query_state=mysql_query(con,loading_csv_query.str().c_str());
```

the h variable is always " " and does'nt take the string.

Comment: So it can only mean that the first `mysql_query` returns zero. Maybe you should check why?

Comment: mysql_query returns zero if success,so it should be zero.am i wrong?

Comment: In that case I think you should update the indentation of the code inside the `if` statements body, and you will see why `loading_csv_query` is not set.

Comment: So apparently your `if` logic is backwards. Do you want `if(mysql_query(con,get_last_id_query.str().c_str()) == 0)`?

Comment: thanks to both of you.i don't know why i did'nt see that.